# How to keep ember bootstrap accordion expanded by default?

Tags: ember.js, ember-bootstrap

what attribute should I pass to keep bootstrap accordion open.

```
<BsAccordion as |acc|>
  <acc.item @value={{1}} @title="First item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button {{on "click" (fn acc.change 2)}}>
      Next
    </button>
  </acc.item>
  <acc.item @value={{2}} @title="Second item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </acc.item>
  <acc.item @value={{3}} @title="Third item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </acc.item>
</BsAccordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<BsAccordion>` component provided by [Ember Bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) has a [`@selected` argument](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.Accordion.html#property_selected). The `AccordionItem`, which `@value` argument matches the `@selected` argument, will be open.

The example given above will show the item with title "*Second item*" as open.

```
<BsAccordion @selected={{2}} as |ac|>
  <acc.item @value={{1}} @title="First item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </acc.item>
  <acc.item @value={{2}} @title="Second item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </acc.item>
  <acc.item @value={{3}} @title="Third item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </acc.item>
</BsAccordion>
```

Please note that this does not prevent the user from changing the currently open item. Doing so could be achieved by resetting `@selected` in the [`@onChange` event](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.Accordion.html#event_onChange).

Comment: One more, if you can help with a way i can keep all the accordions open at first.

Comment: Bootstrap's [accordion component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/) does not support having multiple items open at the same time. Neither Ember Bootstrap's [`<Accordion>` component](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/components/accordion) does.